# Bash Shell Get n number of lines considering duplicate numbers as one

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose I have file with following numbers:

```
123
123
125
126
126
127
128
130
131
132
133
134
```

Then I want to get specific (say n=4) first numbers from file considering duplicates as one.
Therefore, output should be like this

```
123
123
125
126
126
127
```

Comment: Are the numbers one per line, all in one line, or can spread over multiple lines ?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Searched ? At what point did you failed ?

Comment: what do you expect as output if `n=4` and `127` exists 2+ times in the file? do you stop output w/ a single `127` or do you print all occurrences of `127`?  will the input always be sorted or could one of the first `nth` numbers show up later in the file (ie, do we need to search the entire file for **all** occurrences of the first `n` distinct numbers)?

Comment: @dash-o & Gilles Qu enot , I have numbers one per line .   , I tried sort "file1.dat" | uniq -c but her i get number of occurence of each number. I want the output as i have mentioned above.

Comment: @markp-fuso yes i need all occurence of 127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- source data may not be sorted (numerically); while the provided sample data appears to be sorted (numerically), comments by the OP about using `sort` lead me to think the data may not be sorted
- OP wants to pull the `xth` through `yth` numbers (based on numerical sort); original question asks for `first 4` numbers from the data with the desired answer appearing to show the `4` smallest numbers (ie, 1st through 4th numbers); additional comment by OP asks about finding `next 4 matches` so I'm looking at a general solution to pull `xth` through `yth` numbers
- desired output should maintain the original order of the input data

Some sample data:

```
$ cat numbers.dat
123
123
125
126
126
127
127
128
130
131
200
202               # data not sorted
 201              # let's see if we can 'ignore' the leading space
203
132               # data not sorted
133
134
```

For starters we'll look at finding the first 4 numbers (based on numerical sort), ie, the `1st` through `4th` numbers:

```
$ x=1 y=4                                                     # set start/end positions

$ sort -un numbers.dat                                        # get a unique list of sorted numbers
123
125
126
127
128
130
131
132
133
134
200
 201
202
203

$ sort -un numbers.dat | sed -n "${x},${y}p"                  # extract lines x=1 through y=4
123
125
126
127

$ sort -un numbers.dat | sed -n "${x},${y}p" > numbers.grep   # store desired numbers
```

At this point we have a list of the numbers we're interested in:

```
$ cat numbers.grep
123
125
126
127
```

Using `grep` can now use this list to pull the matching rows from the source while also maintaining the original ordering:

```
$ grep -f numbers.grep numbers.dat
123
123
125
126
126
127
127
```

Some examples with different `x` and `y`:

```
$ x=5 y=8
$ sort -un numbers.dat | sed -n "${x},${y}p" > numbers.grep
$ cat numbers.grep
128
130
131
132
$ grep -f numbers.grep numbers.dat
128
130
131
132

$ x=9 y=20
$ sort -un numbers.dat | sed -n "${x},${y}p" > numbers.grep
$ cat numbers.grep     # sorted list of numbers we're interested in
133
134
200
 201
202
203
$ grep -f numbers.grep numbers.dat
200                    # keep in mind this is the order in which the data appears in the source (one of the assumptions)
202
 201
203
133
134
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows:

- First sort the file
- Then only take the different values (remove the duplicates)
- From that, only take the first 4
- Use those values as an input for "grepping" the original file (there are plenty of posts on how to grep a file on the content of another file)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
sed "/`cat file1 | sort | uniq | sed '4q;d'`/q" file1
```

```
123
123
125
126
126
127
```

Mind the `double quotes` to evaluate the expression inside back quotes.

Comment: It works but with numbers sorted. if numbers are not sorted in order than result is undesired. I included sort command like this but it gives error. sed "/`cat sort file1 | uniq | sed '4q;d'`/q" file1

Comment: try like this - ```sed "/`cat file1 | sort | uniq | sed '4q;d'`/q" file1```

Comment: There is also a problem if i add on more 127. Now my input becomes 123
123
125
126
126
127
127
128
130
131
132
133
134   but output is 123
123
125
126
126
127 instead of 123
123
125
126
126
127 127

Comment: I don't know if there is a better solution, but you can match the 5th line instead of 4th and then delete the last line like ```sed "/`cat file1 | sort | uniq | sed '5q;d'`/q" file1 | sed '$d'```

Comment: @Thanks a alot for helping out. Can you tell me how can i get next 4 matches, like this, untill i reach end of file. I mean if i have long list of numbers than i get first four desired numbers using sed "/`cat file1 | sort | uniq | sed '4q;d'`/q" file1. Then How i get next 4 desired number and so on. In last if not exactly 4 numbers are left then how can i deal with it.